# CSS - How to make sure an animation doesn't stop until not hovering?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

So I am learning about CSS animations for the first time, and I've stumbled across a problem.

Let's say I have a simple `div` with a width change animation on hover.

The problem is that the `div` goes back to 350px even if you're still hovering it. Is there a way to prevent that, so that the `div` stays to 400px until you are not hovering it?

Here is the code:

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: black;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: hoverAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

div:not(:hover) {
  animation-name: stopAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes hoverAnimation {
  from {width: 350px}
  to {width: 400px}
}

@keyframes stopAnimation {
  from {width: 400px}
  to {width: 350px}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And here is the code without the `div:not(:hover)` animation, which doesn't work either.

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: black;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: hoverAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes hoverAnimation {
  from {width: 350px}
  to {width: 400px}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Sorry if this is a little confusing. All this is still fairly new to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: anmation-fill-mode: forwards

Answer (score 2):

I've slightly changed your code to instead use a `transition` for the width change of the `div` when hovered.

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width .5s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```